# Six nested loops in order to obtain the difference of arrays within a threshold

Tags: python, numpy, nested, difference

For the data sets posted below,

I am trying to obtain the values of `x_1`, `y_1`, `x_2`, `y_2`, `z_1`, `z_2` for which:

`x_1 = x_2` (within a threshold) AND `y_1 = y_2` (within a threshold) AND `z_1 = z_2` (within a threshold).

I have written this scheme of 6 nested loops:
but this code is running in loops without finishing.

After a lot of checks, I do not understand where is the problem, 
I would appreciate if you could help me

```
import numpy as np
y_1, z_1, x_1 = np.loadtxt('./data_set_1.txt').T    
y_2, z_2, x_2 = np.loadtxt('./data_set_2.txt').T

threshold_z = 0.000005  
threshold_x = 0.000000
threshold_y = 0.000005  

I = []
J = []
K = []
L = []
M = []
N = []

for i in z_1:
 for j in z_2:
  for k in x_1:
   for l in x_2:
    for m in y_1:
     for n in y_2:
       if abs(i - j) < threshold_z:
        I.append(i)
        J.append(j)
       elif abs(k - l) < threshold_x:
        K.append(k)
        L.append(l)
       elif abs(m - n) < threshold_y:
        M.append(m)
        N.append(n)

print "I = ",  I
print "J = ", J

print "K = ",  K
print "L = ", L

print "M = ",  M
print "N = ", N
```

Data sets:

`data_set_1.txt`: https://pastebin.com/VQrsv8kU

`data_set_2.txt`: https://pastebin.com/jFBa6kZq

Comment: the indentation does not seem right. try to correct this and run again

Comment: You have *6 nested loops*. Long ones! Overall, you're trying to execute almost a billion billion iterations.

Comment: You don't need to nest all the loops. A simple optimization would be to find the `x`s, `y`s and `z`s in 3 seperate sets of only doubly nested loops. That would be `O(n^2)`, where as this is `O(n^6)`

Comment: Think carefully before you write a loop. Think really carefully before you write a nested loop. Think really really really really really carefully before you nest 6 deep.

Comment: Lord above. Just use pandas.

Comment: I've got a foundational kind of question: is there supposed to be any kind of correlation between the values you find from each column? Do they have to be in the same row? I don't know that they should be one way or the other, but as written, they're not constrained, which seems odd to me.

Comment: @mwchase `z` is a funciton of `x` and `y` => `z=z(x,y)`, so that each row, for example for `data_set_1.txt`,  contains  `x_1`,  `y_1` and `z_1` . Similarly, `data_set_2.txt`,  contains  `x_2`,  `y_2` and `z_2`

Comment: What is the reason of a negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no obvious reason to go more than 2 deep:

```
for k in x_1:
    for l in x_2:
        if abs(k - l) < threshold_x:
            K.append(k)
            L.append(l)

for m in y_1:
    for n in y_2:
        if abs(m - n) < threshold_y:
            M.append(m)
            N.append(n)

for i in z_1:
    for j in z_2:
        if abs(i - j) < threshold_z:
            I.append(i)
            J.append(j)
```

But you could probably make these faster without using explicit Python-level loops at all.

```
cond = np.abs(x_1 - x_2) < threshold_x
K = x_1[cond]
L = x_2[cond]

// similar for y and z
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to filter out values which do not satisfy the condition

> x_1 = x_2 (within a threshold) AND y_1 = y_2 (within a threshold) AND z_1 = z_2 (within a threshold)

you can modify the condition:

```
cond = ((np.abs(x_1 - x_2) < threshold_x) &
        (np.abs(y_1 - y_2) < threshold_y) &
        (np.abs(z_1 - z_2) < threshold_z))

K = x_1[cond]
L = x_2[cond]
M = y_1[cond]
N = y_2[cond]
I = z_1[cond]
J = z_2[cond]
```

---

**EDIT 2:** The intent of the asker was to determine pairs of points `(x, y, z)` which are some distance apart from each other between the two data sets. There are some approaches to similar problems given in the following two links:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113093/finding-all-nearby-points-in-a-point-cloud
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129892/find-all-points-within-a-certain-distance-of-each-other

I'm sure there are existing library solutions which implement at least some portion of these methods.

If such solutions are not desirable, we may attempt to come up with a simpler solution. The brute force (computationally expensive) way of doing so is:

```
def within_tolerance(p1, p2):
    tol_z = 0.000005
    tol_x = 0.000000  # shouldn't this be 0.000005?
    tol_y = 0.000005

    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2

    return abs(x1 - x2) < tol_x and abs(y1 - y2) < tol_y and abs(z1 - z2) < tol_z

points_1 = list(zip(x_1, y_1, z_1))
points_2 = list(zip(x_2, y_2, z_2))

collisions = []

for p1 in points_1:
    matches = [p2 for p2 in points_2 if within_tolerance(p1, p2)]
    collisions.append(matches)
```

This is of course `O(m * n)`, for `m` and `n` number of points within the two data sets. (Further optimizations may be made for these particular data sets, as I describe in the comments below, if this is not fast enough.)

Comment: Judging by the response to my comment above, the intent appears to be that all three of the coordinates should fall within the thresholds at the same time.

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq As seen in the post, and as mwchase has commented, the goal would be to find `x_1 = x_2 and y_1 = y_2 and z_1 = z_2`

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq  Thank you, - but since the shapes of both data sets are different, if you try loading the `data_set_1.txt` and `data_set_2.txt` provided in the post and using your `cond` answer, you receive `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1700,) (400,)` -

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, there are conceptually two lists of points, and the intent is to find pairs of points, one in each list, that are "similar" according to a metric.

Comment: A *nearly* equivalent rephrasing of this problem would then be "reject points which collide (within a radial distance)". [Relevant](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129892/find-all-points-within-a-certain-distance-of-each-other), [links](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113093/finding-all-nearby-points-in-a-point-cloud).

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq If you fell the title of this post shall be different, feel free to edit it. I don't quite understand the reason for a negative vote, though. Your `cond` answer seemed an excellent approach, but it does not work because the array of both data sets have different length. I only created this post because after a lot of squeezing my brain I could not reach to a solution for many weeks. I would appreciate if someone could help me. Those other links you posted are oriented to a much more complicated problem than this.

Comment: A simple solution (but not generally optimal) would be to sort your data sets by the z values. Then, you can loop through and compare only z values which are near each other (within tolerance). Looking at your dataset, this should be quite fast (1700-10000 "iterations"). If you need more details, I can write an example tomorrow. Side note: I didn't downvote. You can use `@Downvoter` to send them a notification.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Because the goal is to find  `x_1 = x_2 and y_1 = y_2 and z_1 = z_2`, by sorting z-wise you would be solving the `z_1 = z_2` statement, but it would not allow you to find `x_1 = x_2 and y_1 = y_2 and z_1 = z_2`

Comment: @DavidC. Try the brute force solution in EDIT 2.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thanks for your excellent algorithm. I apologise for the late reply, but it has taken me several weeks to understand the way your algorithm works and why you used those list comprehensions, as well as every line statement in your code. I wanted to check the result obtained, so I then learned `sql`, and that took me some other weeks. Then, I could manage to write a `sql` code that produced the same result as your algorithm. Please see my answer to the post. Again, thank you very much, this has been a long process but finally I could collect all the seeds and give raise to a plant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mateen Ulhaq brilliant answer, I have runned the similar algorithm in `sql`. The following proves that by `sql` the same answer is obtained, and therefore this is a support for @Mateen Ulhaq's algorithm (I have not measured the time it takes compared with python).

First of all, if we rewrite `collisions` into `collisions_1` and `collisions_2` in this way:

```
def within_tolerance(p1, p2):
    tol_z = 0.05 
    tol_x = 20.0 
    tol_y = 0.05 

    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2

    return abs(x1 - x2) < tol_x and abs(y1 - y2) < tol_y and abs(z1 - z2) < tol_z

points_1 = list(zip(x1, y1, z1))
points_2 = list(zip(x2, y2, z2))

collisions_2 = []

for p1 in points_1:
    matches = [p2 for p2 in points_2 if within_tolerance(p1, p2)]
    collisions_2.append(matches)

collisions_1 = []

for p2 in points_2:
    matches = [p1 for p1 in points_1 if within_tolerance(p1, p2)]
    collisions_1.append(matches)
```

The result is the following:

collisions_1.dat:

```
# T1              P1               G1
753.7400000000000 9.1661260271200 -941.3907886748256
773.8400000000000 9.1913866075400 -941.3917472784309
793.9400000000001 9.2167924919500 -941.3927256138520
814.0400000000000 9.2423351703100 -941.3937233650445
834.1400000000000 9.2680067572900 -941.3947402226399
```

collisions_2.dat:

```
# T1              P1               G1
753.7400000000000 9.1218048358000 -941.3923833169222
773.8400000000000 9.1691387036100 -941.3930668124686
793.9400000000001 9.2165506846500 -941.3937709718723
814.0400000000000 9.2640367978700 -941.3944954165056
834.1400000000000 9.3115932963000 -941.3952397798080
```

In `sql` the program would be:

```
.headers on

CREATE TABLE C_I("P1" TEXT, "G1" TEXT, "T1" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE C_II("P2" TEXT, "G2" TEXT, "T2" TEXT);

.separator " "

.import './solid_1__xyz_sorted_as_P_wise.dat'  C_I
.import './solid_1__xyz_sorted_as_P_wise.dat'  C_II


select T1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select P1 from C_I LIMIT 3;
select G1 from C_I LIMIT 3;


DELETE FROM C_I WHERE T1 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE P1 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_I WHERE G1 == 'P';

DELETE FROM C_II WHERE T2 == '(Gpa)';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE P2 == '#';
DELETE FROM C_II WHERE G2 == 'P';


select * from C_I LIMIT 3;
select * from C_II LIMIT 3;


SELECT * FROM   C_I l1,  C_II l2
WHERE
    ABS(l1.P1-l2.P2) < 0.05
    AND
    ABS(l1.T1-l2.T2) < 20.0
    AND
    ABS(l1.G1-l2.G2) < 0.05;
```

If you run it as: `sqlite3 < tables.sql` you get:

```
# P1 G1 T1 P2 G2 T2
9.1661260271200 -941.3907886748256 753.7400000000000 9.1218048358000 -941.3923833169222 753.7400000000000
9.1913866075400 -941.3917472784309 773.8400000000000 9.1691387036100 -941.3930668124686 773.8400000000000
9.2167924919500 -941.3927256138520 793.9400000000001 9.2165506846500 -941.3937709718723 793.9400000000001
9.2423351703100 -941.3937233650445 814.0400000000000 9.2640367978700 -941.3944954165056 814.0400000000000
9.2680067572900 -941.3947402226399 834.1400000000000 9.3115932963000 -941.3952397798080 834.1400000000000
```

which is exactly the same result as `collisions_1.dat` and `collisions_2.dat`